# Adding user values from ADFS server to AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have configured the ADFS server, added a user with name as 'test name' and email id as test@domain.com. I have a city field in adfs server with a value added to it as 'city name'.

[image]

I have defined the claim issuance policy with following values in it

[image]

I have a sign up page where the user gets redirected to the adfs server, user gets log in and user gets registered on AAD.

The adfs server sends required values after login to the signup page where these values gets populated in the input fields.

[image]

On AAD user gets registered as Unknown user with no user details.

[image]

City field is empty and other values as well in the details page of user.

[image]

I have following output claims in it trust framework extension.

[image]

Let me know if I am doing the wrong attribute mapping.

How can I add the city value or all the user details on AAD after user signup?

Answer (score 0):

When you say AAD, I assume you mean AAD B2C?

Are you federating B2C with ADFS via SAML or OIDC?

Are the ADFS values populated in the B2C sign-up page?

If so, are you writing these values back to AAD B2C afterwards?

e.g. by using "AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId". If so, have you added these extra values as output claims?

Note that you can only write [these values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes) back.